# strange update notice

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

Is this normal? I don't have `flashplugin` installed.

> Failure to download extra data filesName-ar.UTF-8: فشل تنزيل ملفات البيانات الإضافيةName-ast.UTF-8: Fallu al descargar ficheros de datos estraName-bn.UTF-8: অতিরিক্ত ডাটা ফাইল ডাউনলোড করতে ব্যর্থ হয়েছেName-bs.UTF-8: Neuspjelo učitavanje dodatnih datoteka  s podacimaName-ca.UTF-8: Ha fallat la baixada dels fitxers de dades addicionalsName-da.UTF-8: Kunne ikke hente ekstra datafilerName-de.UTF-8: Herunterladen von zusätzlichen Datendateien schlug fehlName-el.UTF-8: Αποτυχία λήψης επιπλέον αρχείων δεδομένωνName-en_AU.UTF-8: Failure to download extra data filesName-en_GB.UTF-8: Failure to download extra data filesName-eo.UTF-8: Fiasko dum elŝutado de pliaj datumdosierojName-es.UTF-8: Fallo al descargar archivos de datos extraName-fi.UTF-8: Ylimääräisten tiedostojen lataus epäonnistuiName-fr.UTF-8: Échec du téléchargement des données supplémentairesName-gd.UTF-8: Dh'fhàillig luchdadh a-nuas faidhlichean dàta a bharrachdName-gl.UTF-8: Fallo na descarga de ficheiros extra de datosName-he.UTF-8: הורדת קובצי נתוני נוספים נכשלהName-hr.UTF-8: Greška pri preuzimanju dodatnih podatkovnih datotekaName-hu.UTF-8: Nem sikerült letölteni az extra adatfájlokatName-id.UTF-8: Gagal mengunduh berkas data ekstraName-it.UTF-8: Scaricamento file dati extra non riuscitoName-ja.UTF-8: 追加データのダウンロードに失敗Name-km.UTF-8: បាន​បរាជ័យ​ក្នុង​ការ​ទាញយក​ឯកសារ​ទិន្នន័យ​បន្ថែមName-lt.UTF-8: Nepavyko atsiųsti papildomų duomenų failųName-lv.UTF-8: Neizdevās lejupielādēt papildus datu failusName-ms.UTF-8: Gagal memuat turun fail data tambahanName-nl.UTF-8: Downloaden van extra gegevensbestanden is misluktName-oc.UTF-8: Fracàs del telecargament de las donadas suplementàriasName-pt_BR.UTF-8: Falha ao baixar arquivos de dados adicionaisName-ro.UTF-8: Eșec la descărcarea fișierelor cu date suplimentareName-ru.UTF-8: Ошибка загрузки дополнительных файлов данныхName-sk.UTF-8: Zlyhalo stiahnutie ďalších dátových súborovName-sl.UTF-8: Napaka med prejemom dodatnih podatkovnih datotekName-sq.UTF-8: Dështoi shkarkimi i skedarëve të të dhënave ekstraName-sv.UTF-8: Misslyckades med att hämta extra datafilerName-tr.UTF-8: Fazladan veri dosyalarını indirme başarısızName-ug.UTF-8: قوشۇمچە سانلىق-مەلۇمات ھۆججەتلىرىنى چۈشۈرۈش مەغلۇپ بولدىName-uk.UTF-8: Не вдалось завантажити додаткові файли данихName-vi.UTF-8: Lỗi khi tải các tập tin dữ liệu bổ sung xuốngName-zh_CN.UTF-8: 下载额外数据文件失败Name-zh_TW.UTF-8: 下載額外資料檔案失敗
>
> The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.
>
> flashplugin-installer
>
> The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download again now.  >Running this command requires an active Internet connection.

Comment: The message is normal. You likely installed ubuntu-restricted-extras and installed flash without realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had explicitly uninstalled flash, however, the messages continued to appear. disconcerting and distracting.

Finally, `sudo apt-get remove update-notifier` did the trick.

Of course, now must manually check for updates, but that beats that persistent microsoft-like annoying reminder.